# How to call dojo widget method from other dojo widget?

Tags: dojox.charting, dojo

I have created Google map widget in Dojo using declare, which has the method `createMarker`.

The map is shown using

```
<div style='min-height:500px'>  
<div data-dojo-type='testjs/bpl/GoogleMapWidget' data-dojo-attach-point='qWidget'></div>
</div>
```

The map is getting displayed.

1) How to call `qWidget.createMarker()` from another widget ?

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me how exactly you want to call `createMarker`, since you have not provided the code for another widget. However, if this widget is templated, you can reference `qWidget` with `this.qWidget`.

As an example, if your code looks like this (taken from [here](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/templated/)):

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dijit/_WidgetBase",
    "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
    "dojo/text!./templates/SomeWidget.html"
], function(declare, _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, template) {

    return declare([_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin], {
        templateString: template
    });

});
```

And `SomeWidget.html` is your HTML:

```
<div style='min-height:500px'>
    <div data-dojo-type='testjs/bpl/GoogleMapWidget' data-dojo-attach-point='qWidget'></div>
</div>
```

You can access `qWidget` inside your widget's `declare` clause, like this:

```
return declare([_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin], {
    templateString: template,

    myWidget: this.qWidget //reference to the widget in your template HTML
});
```

Comment: is it possible to access myWidget property from outside the widget?

Comment: Yes, once you instantiate the widget.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what the hierarchy is with your widgets. If one of the widgets is a child of the other one (being used in the template of the other one for example), you can use the name referenced in the `data-dojo-attach-point` variable to get your child widget instance, and call the methods on it.

So, assuming the template of the parent widget is the HTML markup you posted in your question:

```html
<div style='min-height:500px'>  
    <div data-dojo-type='testjs/bpl/GoogleMapWidget' data-dojo-attach-point='qWidget'></div>
</div>
```

It means you can access the `testjs/bpl/GoogleMapWidget` by using `this.qWidget`. However, you have to inherit from `dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin` to do that (otherwise attach points will only work for DOM nodes). So your parent widget may look like this:

```js
define([ "dojo/_base/declare", "dijit/_WidgetBase", "dijit/_TemplatedMixin", "dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin" ], function(declare, _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin) {

    return declare([ _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin ], {
        someMethod: function() {
            this.qWidget.createMarker();
        }
    });
});
```

---

If both widgets are independant (no parent widget that "controls" them), then the best way of calling another widget is by using the `dojo/topic` module. For example:

```js
define([ "dojo/topic", "dojo/_base/declare", "dijit/_WidgetBase", "dijit/_TemplatedMixin" ], function(topic, declare, _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin) {

    return declare([ _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin ], {
        someMethod: function() {
            topic.publish("/testjs/createMarker", { });
        }
    });
});
```

And the other widget could then listen to it:

```js
define([ "dojo/topic", "dojo/_base/declare", "dojo/_base/lang", "dijit/_WidgetBase", "dijit/_TemplatedMixin" ], function(topic, declare, lang, _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin) {

    return declare([ _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin ], {
        postCreate: function() {
            this.inherited(arguments);
            topic.subscribe("/testjs/createMarker", lang.hitch(this, this.createMarker));
        }

        createMarker: function() {
            // Do stuff
        }
    });
});
```

This last approach is great for completely unrelated widgets to communicate with each other through the publisher/subscriber pattern (also known as the observer/observable pattern).